# Scale UIWebview with content of page scaling with it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to mimic the tabbing system of the mobile safari app. When you go into tab mode, it looks like the page is shrinking. In my app, i have tried 3 different ways to achieve this effect.

1) capture image of the UIWebView, hide the web view and scale the image.
2) scale the UIWebView
3) apply a transform to the web view.

The first way is one of the best, except if i rotate the screen, the image is funky looking, because it ether expands the image, or shrinks the image.

The second way doesn't work, The web view does skink but it basically just zooms in on the web view content, so if your on google.com, it would zoom into the google logo or somewhere on the page, instead of keeping how it looks when not zoomed, and shrinking that.

The third way also works! except using transforms i don't see a way of controlling the x, y, width and height of the web view. i can add a translation or scale it, but with rotation, it doesnt work that well.

for portrait size of the web view on an iPhone 5 im trying to make it (64, 91.5, 192, 315), and landscape CGRectMake(113, 65, 341, 161). How can I fix this to make it scale right?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The transform approach is likely to be the best; when you apply a transform to a layer (including indirectly via the view) you instruct the GPU to do something special when compositing it. So you have free rein to do whatever you want without the view's logic on how to fit things into a particular space having any effect. As it's all a composition effect, the original pixel rendering of the view is unchanged.

However, when you rotate the device you want to adjust the view itself because what you actually want is for the web view to relayout content.

If you're just literally emulating Safari then use the view's `frame` to set the normal full screen layout; when you want to show the zoomed out view also apply a scaling transform and create a suitable paged scrollview to swipe between pages. If the device rotates then that should affect the `frame` and the scrollview but not the transform.

Comment: I applied the transform `CGAffineTransform position = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -30);
        CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6, 0.7);
        self.webViewObject.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(position, scale);` which looks nice, when rotating, if i do nothing, then its in zoomed out portrait size still. If i make the frame the normal size, it goes bigger, even with applying the transform again right after. And if i apply the frame to a zoomed out frame, it works except when zooming in, then its not on the same frame.